# Include entitlements file in a SPM's package

Tags: swift, healthkit, swift-package-manager

I currently have a `.testTarget` used to test a package that relies on HealthKit. In order to test I can write and read data from Apple HealthKit, I require an entitlement, otherwise I get:

```
"Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement.}
```

My question is: how can I add a dummy entitlement file to bypass this situation? Or maybe there's another way to test HealthKit via a `.testTarget`.

Comment: No nothing so far.